# How to create a "bbcode" javascript with replace

Tags: javascript, for-loop, replace

Markup:

```
<div class="post">
    [tag]dfghf[/tag][tag]gh[/tag][tag]cxbcvb[/tag][tag]gh[/tag][tag]cxbcvb[/tag][tag]gh[/tag]
</div>
```

JS I have so far-

```
for(var j=0;j<post.length;j++){
    var postText = $(post[j]);
    postText.html(postText.html()
                          .replace('[tag]','<span class="tag">')
                          .replace('[/tag]','</span>')
    );
}
```

Though this seems to only replace the very first tag. How do I get it to replace all the tags?

Comment: Yes, use regex with global replace instead of loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
postText.html(postText
              .html()
              .replace(/\[tag\]/g,'<span class="tag">')
              .replace(/\[\/tag\]/g,'</span>')
              );
```

Ex:

```
$('.post').html(function(){
    return $(this)
    .html()
    .replace(/\[tag\]/g,'<span class="tag">')
    .replace(/\[\/tag\]/g,'</span>')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/grEqv/)